# Force.com email service

Tags: email, force.com

I have created an email service in force.com.Can anyone help me out of how to use thta in apex classes.say,i wanna send mail when user registration is successful??

Many Thanks,
Sandhya Krishnan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to send an email directly from Apex code, either in a Trigger or from a page controller ... ?  If so, this page can get you started:

http://www.forcetree.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-your-apex-class.html

Clearly you don't want to hard-code your email template into your classes, so make sure to read at least through the part that shows how to look up the template dynamically.  That should be enough to get you on your way.

Comment: Also something to be wary of: you say you've created an email service that users can sign up to, keep in mind that the number of emails you can send from a Salesforce org are limited to 1000 daily.